# Can't understand this scanner or addition command

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, addition

I'm very new to Java and don't quite understand it all fully, I'm working on a Uni workshop assignment but am having trouble with this particular question.

"Write a program that asks the user to enter how many minutes they have used, and how many texts they have used. 
Both inputs should be whole numbers (integers). 
The program should then calculate the user’s mobile phone bill, assuming that texts cost 7p and calls 12p. 
Should display price of calls, texts and the total bill, both figures added together"

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);                             
System.out.println("How many minutes have you used?");
String one = userInput.nextLine();
System.out.println("How many texts have you used?"); 
String two = userInput.nextLine(); 
int a = 12; 
int b = 7;
System.out.println("The total cost of your minutes is "+one); 
System.out.println("The total cost of you texts is "+two); 
System.out.println("The total cost of your phone bill is "+one + two);
```

I have the basic part to the question figured out, but can't figure out why I can't add to the code for it to figure out the price, being 12 p for minutes, and 7p for texts. As well as this I can't get the total cost of the phone bill to add together correctly. I did earlier and I know it's very easy, but I've completely forgotten how to do it.

I know I need to be able to understand a scanner better, but I did the previous tasks easy enough but this has really stumped me tbh. Do I need to rename the scanner, but when I change the name of the integer line to something like "totalCostOfTexts/Minutes etc" it either says it has already been defined, or is missing some kind of symbol.

Any feedback is appreciated.

I add the code :

```
int = userInput = minutes * 12:
```

As that's what is used in the previous part of a similar question, but all the feedback I get is that it is not a statement, so it can't process. I'm really struggling with this tbh.

Comment: "The total cost of your phone bill is "+one + two shoudl be "The total cost of your phone bill is "+(one + two)

Comment: As a note, your variable names are random and have nothing to do with their contents. Names should describe what's stored in them.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will work for you

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);                             
System.out.println("How many minutes have you used?");
int one = userInput.nextInt();
System.out.println("How many texts have you used?"); 
int two = userInput.nextInt(); 
int a = 12;      //don't use such variable names
int b = 7;       
int minute_bill=12*a;   //see the variable,will make things easier to review
int text_bill=7*b;
int result=minute_bill+text_bill;
System.out.println("The total cost of your minutes is "+minute_bill); 
System.out.println("The total cost of you texts is "+ text_bill); 
System.out.println("The total cost of your phone bill is "+result);
```

and also

- You can use `Scanner's` `nextInt()` method for taking `integer` input
  from console.
- Don't use such variable names like `a,b` etc. define them according to the attribute whose value you are storing in them (see above `minute_bill` and `text_bill` are making the code clean and easy to review)
- And if you are bound to get String value from console,but want to convert entered value  to Integer later on, then you can do it like following code

  ```
  String mystring=userInput.nextLine();   //userInput is user Scanner's object
  int num=Integer.parseInt(mystring);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do...

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);                             
    System.out.println("How many minutes have you used?");
    int one = Integer.valueOf(userInput.nextLine());
    System.out.println("How many texts have you used?"); 
    int two= Integer.valueOf(userInput.nextLine());
    int a = 12; 
    int b = 7;
    System.out.println("The total cost of your minutes is "+ (one * 12); 
    System.out.println("The total cost of you texts is "+ (two * 7)); 
    System.out.println("The total cost of your phone bill is "+ ((one * 12) + (two * 7));
```